# Webpack2 externals for Angular2

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm creating an Angular2 library, so I want to define Angular2 as external dependency.

Reading the documentation on this subject (which is scarce), I would expect the following to work:

```
externals: {
    'moment': 'moment',
    '@angular/core': '@angular/core'
}
// or externals: ['moment', '@angular/core']
```

But this generates an error for @angular/core as webpack produces the following invalid javascript as a result:

```
module.exports = @angular/core;
```

Did I misunderstand how `externals` should be used? The only way to get valid javascript is to use a valid identifier, like so:

```
externals: {
    'moment': 'moment',
    '@angular/core': 'mySpecialLittleUnicorn'
}
```

But obviously, this library will never exist. Are my library users supposed to define an alias 'mySpecialLittleUnicorn' for '@angular/core' or something (how?).

How is this supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack supports several formats for requiring modules after it has been built. for example, to support commonjs, you would add the prefix commonjs to the external (or set your own library to export as commonjs).

`output.libraryTarget: "commonjs2"`

or

`externals: { '@angular/core': 'commonjs @angular/core' }`

However, to support all module types and export your own library for all module types, the best way is to declare externals for all types as well as build your own library for all types.

Externals for all types:

```
    '@angular/core': {root: ['ng', 'core'], commonjs: '@angular/core', commonjs2: '@angular/core', amd: '@angular/core'},
```

Export your own build for all types: [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44340865/441662).