# Writing an Angular library, is it safe to assume users will use commonjs?

Tags: angular

I'm writing a library for Angular2+ users (who would import it before building their own distributions) and to exclude Angular itself from the distribution, I need to do some configuration (in my case include [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx) in the Webpack config).

To make this work, [according to the Webpack maintainers](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4974#issuecomment-305644894), I need to assume my library's users use commonjs.

Is it reasonable to assume Angular users use nodejs? Or can we say that whatever bundler/build tool they are using will support nodejs? I don't want to ignore groups of Angular users. What about just releasing the source code? I think assuming TypeScript is safer for Angular2 users than assuming commonjs.

Comment: angular libraries should target UMD (for dynamic module loaders) and publish metadata.json / d.ts files for AoT static bundles.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: wasn't me...... Node.js is server-side. Your clients (who are browser-based) will not depend on node.js at all. Node.js is like powershell. Its a scripting language on top of an server-side API (chromium V8 engine that is Node.JS)

Comment: If you want to build a simple module library, you can check out one of many seeds out there. Here is one: https://github.com/acme-company/ng-module-template. It targets UMD, AMD, CJS bundles and emits metadata/.d.ts for AoT builds.

Comment: Are you saying it's impossible with Webpack? The current config is very simple. Except of course for the `externals` part, that bit still confuses me.

Comment: No, i'm saying expecting angular users to rely on node.js is like asking browsers to depend on PowerShell.

Comment: > "Your clients (who are browser-based)". This I don't understand. They write Angular code including requires/imports, which are resolved using a bundler/builder. This is not in the browser. Ofcourse Webpack supplies an import system inside the produced bundle, but first the referenced libraries are packaged,  minimified, etc. along in node

Comment: Browsers today don't natively understand CommonJS - that's why you need something like RequireJS, Browserify, SystemJS etc

Comment: I know that. I'm asking if deciding in build-time what module system users use *in their build time* is safe. I'm not talking about running in the browser, I'm talking about users using my library in their code, before building their own distribution packages.

Comment: Then targeting UMD should be safe (any module loader can load it).  Targeting CommonJS limits your users.

Comment: Ahh ok. I will check it out. Thanks. Come to think of it, perhaps releasing the library through NPM only as source code might be the best solution? Only problem then is limiting users to TypeScript, although for Angular2 this is the standard I think.

Comment: You don't have to release the source code. There are generally two ways for an angular app to consume another angular module installed through NPM:   1. dynamically as a UMD bundle (need SystemJS, RequireJS, AMD, etc). or 2. statically through AoT compilation (need published metadata.json and .d.ts files). In either case, the source code (js or ts files) are not needed in the distribution.  The .d.ts files are nice to have - you should include them in the distro.

Comment: If you can rephrase the two approaches as an answer (perhaps with some citations), I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: It should be noticed that UMD bundles should be kept separate for Angular, like it is done in Angular itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To some extend yes, assuming anything about your library user's environment is bad. However, commonjs is supported by virtually all bundlers. UMD is even better supported (since it is compatible with commonjs and AMD), so that would be a safer bet.

However, with the right config you can support commonjs, esmodules and UMD without much extra config. The difference is in building the first two is done with the TypeScript compiler (reusing the same tsconfig.json), while the UMD distribution is build with Webpack.

[Compiling and bundling TypeScript libraries with Webpack](http://marcobotto.com/compiling-and-bundling-typescript-libraries-with-webpack/) explains the setup in details, which includes a [demo repo](https://github.com/elboman/typescript-lib-example) that I [forked and completely upgraded](https://github.com/bbottema/typescript-lib-example), pull request [pending](https://github.com/elboman/typescript-lib-example/pull/1).

Aside from this, apparently it is possible to provide AOT build, but I don't know much about that. The only AOT I know is Angular's compiler for precompiling @Components so the browser doesn't have to do it (performance and dist size optimisation).